# SSIS for transforming data between different versions of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I have hit a roadblock to creating a SSIS package. I have source tables in SQL Server 2008 R2. The package is supposed to be calling complex stored procedures that will query the source tables and store the resultset in the destination table. We need to be able to store the result set (destination tables) in SQL Server 2012 or 2016 as that is the version on all our environments. Do we need to migrate the source database that contains the tables and stored procedures to SQL Server 2012 or above or could we use SSIS to query SQL Server 2008 R2 and then dump the records in 2012 or above. Could somebody throw light on this

Comment: No. You don't. Just try it. SSIS deals with data sources and data targets.

Comment: The benefit from *upgrading* the database is "simply" that 2008R2 is no longer supported. 2016 is a *lot* faster and offers features like partitioning, compression, columnstores, in-memory tables that either weren't available in 2008 R2 or were only available in the Enterprise edition. You can get orders of magnitude better performance from the same hardware

Comment: Ideally what version of SSIS should I be using. SDT for visual studio 2015 only support SQL server 2012,2014,2016 and VNext.

Comment: Just because it's called SSIS 2016 doesn't mean it can't load data from 2008 R2. Use the latest version available.

Comment: If you had taken 15 minutes to try it you would find the second option works fine. Doesn't anybody try anything for themselves anymore?

Answer (score 0):

> Do we need to migrate the source database that contains the tables
>   and stored procedures to SQL Server 2012 or above

No.

> or could we use SSIS to query SQL Server 2008 R2 and then dump the
>   records in 2012 or above.

Yes, yes you can.  This is exactly what SSIS was made to do ... transfer data between systems, regardless of version, OS, or medium.  It's an integration tool.

To get started, launch Visual Studio / SSDT.
From the menubar, select New -> Project -> Business Intelligence -> Integration Services Project.

At the bottom of the screen is the Connection manager.  Right-click inside there and create two new connections.  One to your 2008 SQL server and another to your 2012+ server.  Then, drag a [DataFlow] object from the toolbar on the left over to the canvas on the right.  Once it's on the canvas, double-click the dataflow object to jump inside. Now - from the toolbox - drag a [OLE DB Source] and an [OLE DB Destination] onto the dataflow canvas.  Double click those and configure them.  Set the [OLE DB Source] to use the 2008 connection. And set the [OLE DB Destination] to use 2012+ connection.  Set the source to call your big SP and use the destinatiion map the columns.  Press the Green button at the top to make the data flow.

Your SSIS package is going to look something like this.

[image]

Good luck!